# Display all the apps that support sending messages (Chatting)

Tags: ios, iphone

I want display all the apps in my app that support chatting. Actually I need to send the selected text via message applications (i.e., WhatsApp, WeChat, etc..) those are installed in my iOS device.

I have gone through UIDocumentInteractionController but it allow to share files only. But here in my case I want to share just text.

Is this possible. Please help me out, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

iOS does not have a single option for sharing text, the [`UIActivityViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) can be used and will show the iOS integrated social networks.

You will be able to add you own service to this dialog, as long a the app has a URL scheme to support its.
A example of a Whatsapp [`UIActivity`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivity_Class/Reference/Reference.html): https://github.com/jberlana/JBWhatsAppActivity

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But android have that functionality to share text , So my client asking me to do the same in iOS. Is there any way to this or any URL schemas for apps this kind other than WhatsApp.

Comment: No, you will need to do it per app. On iOS there is not functionality like on Android.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the URL schemes (if the chatting app provides one) of the app, you can check if a app exists or not using -canOpenURL: of UIApplication class. If they support url schemes, you can send text in the format that those app supports.

Comment: Thanks, I know the URL schemes concept, but here I need to share the text like how we can share the documents by using UIDocumentInteractionController.